# WebStorm has marked all files in a directory as non-project files

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea, webstorm

WebStorm has marked all files in a subdirectory of my project (the server portion of the root) as **non-project files**.

It happened sometime during my conversion to Babel and then again to TypeScript. I've removed the TypeScript stuff, wondering if it's something to do with that configuration. I believe it's just a WebStorm setting somewhere - because my tests run, builds work, all that.

Whenever I refactor or rename a file it says:

> "Selected element is used from non-project files. These usages won't be renamed. Proceed anyway?"

It also highlights the code in these files differently.

Each of these file's icons has a small `x` in the top corner.

[In their docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/non-project-files-access-dialog.html) it says that these are " non-project files (e.g, library sources, external sources etc." This makes me think at some point I just marked a whole folder external at some point, thought I don't know where that could be.

**Update** I've tried deleting `.idea` folder and then running *invalidate cache and restart*. This didn't fix it either.

The `myProject.iml` file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module type="WEB_MODULE" version="4">
  <component name="NewModuleRootManager">
    <content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$">
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/.tmp" />
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/temp" />
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/tmp" />
    </content>
    <orderEntry type="inheritedJdk" />
    <orderEntry type="sourceFolder" forTests="false" />
  </component>
</module>
```

Comment: can be related to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-30895; please check your `.idea/workspace.xml` - do you have any entries like `<component name="TypeScriptGeneratedFilesManager">` with `<option name="exactExcludedFiles">` in it?

Answer (score 24):

Close all Webstorm windows and from project folder in terminal run:

```
rm -rf .idea
```

Note: deleting from within Webstorm is not enough.

Comment: This seems like a good solution, since I don't have this issue anymore I'm not sure how to verify it - so I'll upvote it but not mark as accepted.

Comment: Worked for me too,  Webstorm thought all my files were external after I had deleted and re-cloned my project.

Comment: In Windows, We need to close WebStorm completely (I have even quit the Toolbox also). After that, go to inside the parent folder of .idea folder and open command prompt from that location and execute this command: `rd /s /q ".idea"`

Comment: Since Jono stated the issue was gone before trying this solution, I can instead verify that this solution worked. Upvote granted. Thanks for this solution!

Comment: it works. looks like it is related to the miss config stuffs

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and none of these solutions didn't work.
Just right-click on the folder that has been marked as none-project, then click on `Mark directory as`, then click on `Cancel Exclusion` or `Not Excluded` and enjoy features of project-files :'))

[screenshot of: how to mark none-project folder, as project folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPfpl.png)